# Comparing two binomial coefficient sums

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, binomial-coefficients

Let $j \in N, n\in N, n>1, q\geq 2$.
I would like to show that
$$
\sum_{j=\frac{n}{\ln n}}^{\sqrt n/2}(2j-n)^q{n \choose j}<\sum_{j=\sqrt n/2}^{{\frac n2}}(2j-n)^q{n \choose j}
$$

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: motivation?${}$

Comment: I am working under some approximation question. I wanted to 'cut out' part of the sum. It seems that the LHS sum is much more smaller then the RHS sum.

Comment: Are you sure about the limits of the LHS?

Comment: cross-posted to MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/94489/one-sum-less-then-another

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to bound the term $(2j-n)^2$ on both sides, use the upper bound on the LHS, and the upper bound on the RHS. Then estimate the binomial sums using the identities
$$ \left( \frac{n}{k} \right)^k \leq \binom{n}{k} \leq n^k, $$
or if you want to be fancier, using Stirling's approximation or even using Berry-Esséen (recall that a binomial distribution is close to a normal distribution).

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain how did you get term $(2j-q)^2$?

Comment: That was just a typo, sorry.